# Proof of $\exists n_0: k^n\leq n!\quad \forall n\geq n_0$

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, factorial

Makes total sense to me intuitively, and it's easy to check for any specific $k$, for example $k=2$:

$2^3 = 8,\quad3! = 6 \quad $ and $\quad 2^4=16, \quad 4! = 24$

$\Rightarrow2^n\leq n! \quad \forall n\geq n_0=4\quad$ since every additional factor on the right side after $n_0$ is greater than 2.

What is the proof for the general $k$ case:

$\exists n_0: k^n\leq n!\quad\forall n\geq n_0$

I would be happy to have one non-induction proof ideally, since it usually is easier to wrap my head around. An induction proof would also be useful though.
Thanks!

Comment: Consider if $f(n)=\frac{k^n}{n!},$ then look at what happens when $n>2k$ to $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}.$

Answer (score 1):

You know that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges because of the ratio test, or even just because you've seen that it equals $e^x$ for all $x$.  Thus for any $x$ you have $\dfrac{x^n}{n!} \to 0$, and in particular for any $x$ there is an index $n_x$ with the property that $n \ge n_x \implies |x^n| \le n!$.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense, but I'm stuck with one point: The ratio test implies that the infinite sum converges, however, I'm boldly assuming that only because an infinite sum converges, any chosen sequence of summands (that "passes" the ratio test) will converge towards 0. This is the essence of my question. I still haven't directly proven that $x^n/n!$ converges towards 0. Am I missing something? How do I prove both directions of the equivalence?

Comment: One of the primary facts about series is that if $\sum_n a_n$ converges, then $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any reference (link) with a comprehensive formulation?

Answer (score 0):

Take a natural number $N$ such that $N\geqslant2k$. Then, if $n\geqslant N$,$$n!=N!\times(N+1)\times(N+2)\times\cdots\times n\geqslant N!\times(2k)^{n-N,}$$and$$N!\times(2k)^{n-N}\geqslant k^n\iff2^n\geqslant\frac{2^Nk^N}{N!}.$$So, take $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $n_0\geqslant N$ and that $2^{n_0}\geqslant\frac{2^Nk^N}{N!}$. If $n\geqslant n_0$, then $2^n\geqslant\frac{2^Nk^N}{N!}$, and therefore $n!\geqslant k^n$.

Answer (score 0):

A more direct approach. It is related to the ratio test, but requires no knowledge of infinite sums or even limits.

If $f(n)=\frac{k^n}{n!}$ then for every $n,$ $$f(n+1)=\frac{k}{n+1}f(n).\tag1$$ This means if $n+1>2k,$ then $f(n+1)<\frac12f(n).$

So given any $n_1+1>2k,$ define $n_0=n_1+1+\lceil\log_2 f(n_1)\rceil.$

Then $$f(n_0)<\frac1{2^{\lceil \log_2 f(n_1)\rceil+1}}f(n_1)<1.$$

But then for $n>n_0>2k-1,$ $(1)$ also shows that $f(n)<1.$